# How to publish NFS shared drive to HTTP using Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, nfs

Is it possible to create a website using HTTP which list all of the contains of my NFS shared drive to the public ?

my goal is to provide file access through HTTP to all of my NFS shared drive that i dedicate for public access.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just make sure that mod_autoindex is enabled, and then in your Apache config, just make sure your NFS directory is within your apache DocumentRoot (or a proper alias created), and then allow Indexes for wherever you have your NFS path:

```
<Directory /path/to/nfs/mount>
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the quick reply, usually i access this drive using "\\IPaddress\shared_vol" in windows so i must figure it out how to mount it first on linux.

Comment: root@sv6:/etc/apache2# showmount
clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered <br>
root@sv6:/etc/apache2# showmount -e 10.2.2.50
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - RPC: Unable to receive
root@sv6:/etc/apache2#

Comment: @Albert - are you sure NFS is enabled on your file server? If you've been accessing it via a UNC path (\\server\share\\), then that's using over CIFS, not NFS.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, it seems that the NFS is not installed in the DNS-323 NAS aplliance.